# How to Start or Stop an existing EC2 instance from a Jenkins Job

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have a Jenkins Job to start and stop AWS EC2 instances. 
Probably the profile is misconfigured and I'm stuck at this :

> *botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile xxxx could not be found*

Using this command through Execute Shell:

```
aws ec2 stop-instances --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --profile $AWS_PROFILE  --instance-ids $INSTANCE
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated to modify the job or resolve this error.

Comment: Check what `$AWS_PROFILE` contains and look in `~/.aws/credentials` to see whether it matches.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I should check this on the Jenkins master or Agent?
The agent says 'no such file or directory'

Comment: An alternate way of gaining credentials is via **Environment Variables**. It might be using them. See: [Configuring the AWS CLI - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)

Comment: what happens when you run "echo $AWS_PROFILE"? It sounds like that variable is not set.

Comment: Hi @dmohr It returns blank.
Configuring the CLI for now and checking if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the profile name you passed in the command. It should be configured in your credentials file, usually found at this location **~/.aws/credentials**

You can follow this guide (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) to set up profile.

Best of luck